# Orientation of checkboxes and their labels in a form

Tags: forms, input-fields, checkboxes

I have a form that has a combination of text fields, checkboxes, drop downs etc.

Generally, UX fundamentals dictate we do this.
[image: Supposed correct way of orienting checkboxes in a form]
This works well when text/drop down fields outnumber checkboxes

But, what if the **checkboxes outnumber text/drop downs**?

### Which one should be the right approach?

**APPROACH 1**

[image: Same way as before (in image 1 above)]

**APPROACH 2**

[image: Keep the checkbox label orientation same as the other fields]

Answer (score 1):

None of the options are recommended. The form is breaking some basic form guidelines, for example:

1. Aligning all fields to the left to follow F browsing pattern
2. Place field labels above fields to avoid unnecessary eye movement
3. Clear use of language (e.g. a checkbox coupled with a "Don't Allow..." is very confusing since you have double negatives couples with a checkbox.)
4. Whenever possible, introduce smart interfaces that cut down on the number of unnecessary selection and clicks. For example, AM/PM, Hours/Minutes, Hour/Week can be radios or pills rather than drop-downs.

Form design best practices:
https://uxdesign.cc/the-ux-behind-designing-better-forms-d6ebe7a817d2

Radio vs pills:
https://uxdworld.com/2018/05/06/7-rules-of-using-radio-buttons-vs-drop-down-menus/

Dropdown design:
https://www.nngroup.com/articles/drop-down-menus/ 
https://baymard.com/blog/drop-down-usability

Incomplete example of what can be done with layout:

[image]

Comment: Great answer and I completely agree with you on all points but unfortunately, I can't do that. I have been breaking my head over it trying to get the customers to understand the issues but it is a 30 y/o application and they don't want to change much. I have a very limited scope here and I am trying to make the best out of a bad situation.

Comment: What are the particular limitations?